# Como saber quais as permissões de uma role no SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Estou fazendo a administração de alguns databases que foram criados antes da minha chegada.

Na maioria deles foi criado uma role chamada `dp_role_analista`, e alguns usuários estão nessa role.

Como faço para saber quais permissões esta role está concedendo para os usuários?

Comment: Essa resposta te ajuda? http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36620/35944

Comment: Infelizmente a consulta que está no link não trouxe o que eu preciso. Ele trouxe somente usuários principais e nem listou a role que eu comentei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O script abaixo lista todos os usuários e suas respectivas *roles*, tanto usuários do banco de dados quanto usuários do servidor, identificando a natureza do usuário.

Deve ser executado no database `master`:

```
SELECT 
[LOGIN TYPE]=
    CASE SP.TYPE
        WHEN 'U' THEN 'WINDOWS'
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQLSERVER'
        WHEN 'G' THEN 'GROUP'
    END,
    CONVERT(CHAR(45), SP.NAME) AS SRVLOGIN, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(45), SP2.NAME) AS SRVROLE,
    CONVERT(CHAR(25), DBP.NAME) AS DBUSER,
    CONVERT(CHAR(25), DBP2.NAME) AS DBROLE
FROM SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS AS SP 
    JOIN SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS AS DBP ON SP.SID = DBP.SID 
    JOIN SYS.DATABASE_ROLE_MEMBERS AS DBRM ON DBP.PRINCIPAL_ID = DBRM.MEMBER_PRINCIPAL_ID 
    JOIN SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS AS DBP2 ON DBRM.ROLE_PRINCIPAL_ID = DBP2.PRINCIPAL_ID 
    LEFT JOIN SYS.SERVER_ROLE_MEMBERS AS SRM ON SP.PRINCIPAL_ID = SRM.MEMBER_PRINCIPAL_ID 
    LEFT JOIN SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS AS SP2 ON SRM.ROLE_PRINCIPAL_ID = SP2.PRINCIPAL_ID
```

Já o script abaixo lista todas as permissões de uma *role*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RP.NAME, 
                OBJECTTYPE = RP.TYPE_DESC, 
                PERMISSIONTYPE = PM.CLASS_DESC, 
                PM.PERMISSION_NAME, 
                PM.STATE_DESC, 
                OBJECTTYPE = CASE 
                               WHEN OBJ.TYPE_DESC IS NULL 
                                     OR OBJ.TYPE_DESC = 'SYSTEM_TABLE' THEN 
                               PM.CLASS_DESC 
                               ELSE OBJ.TYPE_DESC 
                             END, 
                [OBJECTNAME] = ISNULL(SS.NAME, OBJECT_NAME(PM.MAJOR_ID)) 
FROM   SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS RP 
       INNER JOIN SYS.DATABASE_PERMISSIONS PM 
               ON PM.GRANTEE_PRINCIPAL_ID = RP.PRINCIPAL_ID 
       LEFT JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SS 
              ON PM.MAJOR_ID = SS.SCHEMA_ID 
       LEFT JOIN SYS.OBJECTS OBJ 
              ON PM.[MAJOR_ID] = OBJ.[OBJECT_ID] 
WHERE  RP.TYPE_DESC = 'DATABASE_ROLE' 
       AND PM.CLASS_DESC <> 'DATABASE' 
ORDER  BY RP.NAME, 
          RP.TYPE_DESC, 
          PM.CLASS_DESC
```

Comment: @JeanBraz Perdão. Vou complementar a resposta.

Comment: Perfeito morrison-mendez agora deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.